# В ячейке таблицы кнопка конфликтует с прокруткой таблицы

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня есть таблица, в ней есть ячейки. Задача такова, что когда пользователь кликает по ячейке таблицы, то должнен открываться другой вьюконтроллер соответствующий id этой ячейки. Поэтому я в ячейке поверх других ui элементов расположил кнопку, которая закрывает весь контент ячейки. В самом классе контроллера я на кнопку задаю таргет (и тег)

```swift
cell.cellClicker.tag = indexPath.row
cell.cellClicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onOrderClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

[image: storyboard]

Проблема в том, что таблица не прокручивается из-за того что кнопка перехватывает все действия. Как сделать так чтобы и таблица прокручивалась и клик по ячейке можно было отлавливать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуй использовать метод делегата `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let id = ids[indexPath.row]
      openOrderAt(id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, для обработки нажатия на ячейку действительно лучше использовать соответствующий делегатный метод, как уже указали, во-вторых, кнопка будет также нормально работать, если не менять выставленное по дефолту в true свойство таблицы **delaysContentTouches**.

Так что оптимальный вариант для обработки нажатий:

1. нажатие **на всю ячейку** - didSelect у делегата таблицы
2. нажатие **на элемент внутри ячейки** - обработчик нажатия (action с touchUpInside в частности). Исходя из того, что элемент НЕ будет при этом занимать всю площадь ячейки (ведь для таких случаев мы используем **п. 1**),  со значением delaysContentTouches можете уже экспериментировать - при true для активации обработчика нажатия потребуется продолжительное нажатие, зато скролл будет работать и если пальцем попасть на кнопку, при false - будут срабатывать обычные нажатия на кнопку, как будто она не заключена внутрь скролл-вью (а таблица является скролл-вью и наследует delaysContentTouches именно оттуда), но при этом скролл не будет срабатывать если попасть пальцем на кликабельные элементы.

Comment: Так то в данном конкретном случае совет помог, но что если в ячейках будут кнопки (например лайки, кликабельные заголовки и прочее). Тогда уже думаю этот совет не подойдёт. А про delaysContentTouches немного не понял. Где это находится? И если по дефолту должно работать нормально, я ничего не менял и теоретически должно быть по дефолту

Comment: Описание delaysContentTouches из доки Apple - If the value of this property is true, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. Т.е. данное свойство указывает нашему ScrollView (а TableView базируется именно на нем), что событие тапа на контент будет вызвано с задержкой, как раз для того чтобы правильно отрабатывал сам скролл. Цитата: "что если в ячейках будут кнопки (например лайки, кликабельные заголовки и прочее)" - в этом случае уже надо вешать таргет на интерактивные элементы и вызывать соответствующий селектор.

Comment: Кнопки и все, что вы хотите чтобы вело себя как "кликабельные" элементы, при delaysContentTouches == true работать будут, только для их активации потребуется продолжительное нажатие. Очевидно связано это с тем, что код сокрытый внутри UITableView сначала будет трактовать тач как начало скролла, и потом если смещения не следует в течение определенного интервала времени, тач трактуется как предназначенный элементу внутри ячейки.

Comment: Расширил ответ, разобрав ситуацию с элементами а-ля "лайки", надеюсь, достаточно однозначно